# Vegetarian substitutes for nuoc mam / nuoc cham?

Tags: vegetarian

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a good substitute for Fish Sauce?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1366/what-is-a-good-substitute-for-fish-sauce)

What makes the best vegetarian substitute for fish sauce (nuoc mam) in Vietnamese dishes and condiments, especially nuoc cham (the nuoc mam prepared with acid, garlic and chilis)?

Comment: You may want to revise the question so as not to be a duplicate of http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1366/what-is-a-good-substitute-for-fish-sauce/1407#1407 ... it looks like that thread addresses the first (nuoc mam) half of your question.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that! Although actually I might reopen this as a question specifically about Vietnamese food - I don't think I'll be putting worcherstire sauce in nuoc cham :)